# How to Create Expanded Sidebar Menu

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am a newcomer to webdesign. I am working on a personal site and I want to organize the menu on the left side of the page, and have it expand to reveal the projects within each category, much like this shopping site: http://www.zara.com/dk/en/woman/shirts-c358004.html.

I cannot figure out where to start, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a site for advice on where to start rather helping out with specific code problems. Here you go: http://bit.ly/UnK901, http://bit.ly/1jezY2Y

Answer (score 1):

this can be done using css as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#leftdiv{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
#rightdiv{
   float:right;
   width:50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="maindiv">
    <div id="leftdiv">
       <!-- Content of div -->
    </div>
    <div id="rightdiv">
       <!-- div content -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```